# DOM onLoad event without jQuery

Tags: javascript, dom-events

HTML code :

```
<html>
   <head>
   </head>
   <body>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/colorbook.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
          book.init();
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

JS code :

```
var book = (function(){
   init = function(){
   console.log ( "initialized")
   }return init();
}());
```

Question : The above code works, but I am unable to understand how? Can any of you help me here or guide me how should I start debug this code to understand it?

Comment: Hmmm so what exactly are you confused about, how the js is executed or why that particular function semantics works?

Comment: @Nomad101 : It would be great if you can help me out with both of it.

Comment: Is that JS code the only code located in the JS file you reference?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so as per your comment. The Javascript you have there is all executed sequentially as the browser reads it from the incoming data stream. That being said, All javascript contained within the first script tag will be executed. Then the second script tag will be executed in sequence as well.

So right now you can look at the `book.init()` as being the last provided javascript call to be executed.

I tried your JS code in jsfiddle and could not get it to work check [This Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TCeYp/30/) to see what I mean.

What is happening in your JS code is the last `()` at the end of the `var book` declaration executes the anonymous function which will print the line to the console. However from the code you supplied the `book` variable never gets a `book.init()` method. So once that call is reached it will throw an error of undefined.